# Unable to download Android Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

every time i try to download android facebook sdk 3.14.1 it gives me network error. Tried it from multiple machines and networks.

Comment: which website you are trying?

Comment: this link is https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-current.zip
from the webpage https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: Known bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/381251638682173/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try from this link, which is the other alternative  https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk.